# Document.write from a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, document.write

I am new to JavaScript. This request seems simple enough but cant seem to get it to work.

I want to select from a drop down menu and return the value in the HTML. As I have it now, it returns the value in a text box, but I want it to write it without using a text box, just simply return it in the `<p></p>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ppk5k/

Comment: So you're asking how to append text to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function favBrowser()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("myList");
document.getElementById("favorite").innerHTML = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text+".";

}
```

You have to use [`innerHTML`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) to set the HTML of `#favorite` to the browser selected.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ppk5k/6/

#### Update

To get the value and text:

```
function favBrowser() {
    var mylist = document.getElementById("myList");
    document.getElementById("favorite").innerHTML = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("favorite").innerHTML += " and the value of that option is " + mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].value + ".";
}
```

If you selected Google Chrome it will output:

> Your favorite browser is Google Chrome and the value of that option
> is G.

And for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ppk5k/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ppk5k/11/   Thanks for the help, one quick question, how do I return the option text and value?

Answer (score 1):

Get the `<p>` by its ID (or by some other method), then set its `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use document.write after the page has loaded, it will replace the page content. You need to use innerHTML or appendChild.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include a `value=""` attribute within the option tags, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function favBrowser() {
        var mylist=document.getElementById('myList');
        document.getElementById('favorite').value=mylist.value;
    }
</script>
<form>
    Select your favorite browser:
    <select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome</option>
        <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>  
        <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
        <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
        <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
    </select>
    <p>Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20" value=""></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is by giving an `id` attribute to a HTML element and change it's innerHTML or clear, create and append a text node to the element:

**innerHTML:**

```
var element = document.getElementById('someElement');
element.innerHTML = "someValue";
```

**appendChild:**

```
var element = document.getElementById('someElement');
var oldChild = element.firstChild;
element.removeChild(oldChild);

var newChild = document.createTextNode("someValue");
element.appendChild(newChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML . [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppk5k/10/)

HTML:

```
<form>
Select your favorite browser:
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>  
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Safari</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
<p id="favorite">Your favorite browser is:
</p>

</form>
```

Javascript :

```
function favBrowser() {
    var mylist = document.getElementById("myList");
    document.getElementById("favorite").innerHTML= "Your favorite browser is: " +  mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
}
```